# How to bring up CSS selector editor window in Visual Sturio 2013?

Tags: css, visual-studio

How is it possible to bring up CSS selector editor window when editing a CSS selector in the text editor? I recall years ago in VS 2008 I've seen something where the developer can edit borders, fonts all styles in a model dialog window, then pressed OK and the CSS selector was updated in the text editor.

Now I am looking this for days and can not find.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hope bellow link give you small help

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398931%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
```

Comment: unfortunatelly msdn is usless as usual. Many words, without an explicit intruction how to open that window... :-(